# Some consequences of the Baire Category Theorem

Tags: baire-category

I read there are some consequences of the Baire Category Theorem in "The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock" by Russel. A. Gordon. The statement is

> **Corollary 5.3.** Let $E$ be a non-empty closed set and let $(E_k)$ be a sequence of sets such that $E=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} E_k$.
> (a) If each $E_k$ is closed, then there exist a portion o$E\cap I$ of $E$ and a positive integer $p$ such that $E\cap I\subseteq E_p$.
> (b) If each $E_k$ is an $F_\sigma$ set, then there exist a portion o$E\cap I$ of $E$ and a positive integer $p$ such that $E\cap I\subseteq E_p$.

*Note: A portion of a set $E$ is a nonempty set of the form $E \cap I$ where $I$ is an open
interval.*

Statements (a) and (b) are quite similar. The difference is only on "each $E_k$ is closed" and "each $E_k$ is an $F_\sigma$ set".
I have proved statement (a). Then, I found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set), it is stated that each closed set is an $F_\sigma$ set.
So, is it enough to prove statement (a) only, because each closed set is an $F_\sigma$ set, so that statements (a) and (b) are the same. 
Or I should prove statement (b) by using statement (a)?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Statements (a) and (b) are **not** the same: the fact that every closed set is $F_\sigma$ tells us that (b) implies (a), not that (a) implies (b). (That said, (b) does quickly reduce to (a) with a bit of thought.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, I see. I misunderstood about that. So, I need to prove statement (b) first, then to prove (a) it is enough to say :  because every closed set is $F_\sigma$, then by (b), we can conclude that (a) is proven, right?